# Download image from String URL

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following button that receives data from a collection view cell and shares a String URL.

However I'm looking for a means to download the actual image from the URL before sharing. How can this be done in Swift?

```
    //get buttonViewShareAction and share image
@IBAction func buttonViewShareAction(sender: UIButton) {
    print("buttonViewShareAction tapped")
    let face = self.faces[sender.tag]

    if let imageURL = NSURL(string:face.image) {
        print(imageURL)
    }        

    let shareItems:Array = [face.image]
    let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "convert the string to an actual image“? What kind of data does the string contain?

Comment: pekka the data contained inside the string is just a URL link to an image, each cell contains a different URL to a different image. The format of the string is as such: `http://domain.com/image.png`

Comment: What you call "convert the string to an actual image" is usually just known as "downloading the data from the URL then making an image from it" and has been explained numerous times already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the image URL, you want to create an `NSData` out of it then create a `UIImage` from this data.

**Swift 3.0**

```
let imageData: Data = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: imageURL)!)
let profileImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!
```

**Swift 2**

```
let imageData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: imageURL)!)!
let profileImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!
```

Comment: NSData is what I needed, after a slight modification your snipped helped solve my issue, thank you.

Comment: Be aware that `contentsOfURL` works synchronously and will block the whole thread in case of an error.